# Assistance with elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a student index with the following mapping and have millions of records in it.A student can have multiple entries in the "student_snapshot" section that shows the history of all his/her enrollments. We want to find all the students in the index that are "current". A student is considered "current" if the student_status is "ACTIVE" or "INITIAL" for the entry in the student_snapshot with the highest enrollment number. So from the above two records, only Jane Smith's document is eligible as the status for the highest enrollment number(9) is Active. Can you help us write a query to accomplish this ? If not what is the performant efficient way to accomplish this.

```
PUT test-student
{

  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "student_name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "student_id":{
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "student_snapshot": {
           "properties": {
          "enrollment_number": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "student_status": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test-student/_doc/1
{
  "student_name": "John Doe",
   "student_id" : "12345",
  "student_snapshot": [
    {
      "enrollment_number": "1",
      "student_status": "Initial"
    },
    {
      "enrollment_number": "2",
      "student_status": "Active"
    },
    {
      "enrollment_number": "3",
      "student_status": "Terminated"
    }
  ]
}
PUT test-student/_doc/2
{
  "student_name": "Jane Smith",
   "student_id" : "789",
  "student_snapshot": [
    {
      "enrollment_number": "5",
      "student_status": "Initial"
    },
    {
      "enrollment_number": "6",
      "student_status": "Discontinued"
    },
    {
      "enrollment_number": "9",
      "student_status": "Active"
    }
  ]
}
```